# Covert typescript class to object

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have a typescript class A and another class B having all properties of class A. Is there a way to copy all values from class B to Class A. Or is there a way to get all properties of class A as an object.

Comment: like [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)?

Comment: You need to copy all field values from variable `a: ClassA` into another variable `b:ClassB`?

Answer (score 0):

Class instances are objects, as such you can use normal object prototype functions ex.

```js
class MyClass {
  _a=0;
  _b=0;
  constructor(a, b){
    this._a=a;
    this._b=b;
  }
  
  set a(a){
    return this._a = a;
  }
  
  get a(){
    return this._a;
  }
  
  set b(b){
    return this._b = b;
  }

  get b(){
    return this._b;
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass(2,3);

console.log("keys", Object.keys(instance))
console.log("values", Object.values(instance))
console.log("entries", Object.entries(instance))

instance.a = 5;
instance.b = 5;

console.log("keys", Object.keys(instance))
console.log("values", Object.values(instance))
console.log("entries", Object.entries(instance))
```

Take into account that it will only return actual parameters, and ignore setters and getters

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question. If you need to copy all field values from class 1 to class 2, you can use:

```js
Object.assign(cl2, cl1);
```

Here is full example ([can test it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QIzQN4ChqegBwK4CMQBLYaMALmgDtcBbfAUwCdoBeaRAbgyz0JOj5KNeszbQATNyw4CxUsGF1GLdgGZuAX25pQkGPH0TUPTH3lkA-EtFNpvOQPzXqy5vbOOFLkSq06QBgAXaFBkdioGAHc4BAguXQB7KghEwIA6EESAcwAKAHJw6HyAGlCQRDKw6CIUoLAqYAZEgDNY-Ury5FqIesbmtsMoCQBKNDRAkNAJSiGIYwjo9uHuAHl8ACsGYCD0-SJsqlzpqoqRnWBk1IysvPyF4tOJJ5q6hqbW5fiXnr6Pwbio04QA), just press "Run"):

```js
class Class1 {
    public a: number = 1;
    public b: number = 2;
    public c: number = 3;
};

class Class2 {
    public a?: number;
    public b?: number;
    public c?: number;
};

let cl1 = new Class1;
console.log('1 = ', cl1, cl1 instanceof Class1, cl1 instanceof Class2)

let cl2: Class2 = new Class2;
Object.assign(cl2, cl1);

console.log('2 = ', cl2, cl2 instanceof Class1, cl2 instanceof Class2);
```

Comment: `cl2` is no instance of `Class2`, all of its own properties and methods are missing.

Comment: @Anton, I am using nest.js and I want to copy data coming from DTO directly into database entity. This copying of data is handled using TypeOrm but only when both classes have the same properties. My scenario is such that my DTO class has properties than my database entity class. My question is basically is there any better way of copying values from one class to another. As of now, I am doing what Krzysztof Krzeszewski has suggested.

Comment: @MustanishAltamash sorry, I do not know nest.js. Maybe you can create new question with this description and add `nestjs` as a tag.